# Seamless way to link time series data from an increasing number of spreadsheets in excel

Tags: excel, connection, excel-2013

I have a task that involves plotting data over time from a set of spreadsheets, where the number of spreadsheets increases by 1 each month.  I'm wondering what the easiest, most user friendly way to do this for novice excel users.

Say I have workbooks in a directory:

xjan19.xlsx

xfeb19.xlsx

xmar19.xlsx

xapr19.xlsx

Each of these workbooks thankfully has the same sheet structure.  suppose I need to extract up to 20 business days of data in a column from sheet "profit" starting from say cell B10 (the exact number of rows in this cell selection isn't fixed for each month).

I need to pull the the data from each of the above four workbooks into a "master.xlsx" workbook (say sheet "profitovertime") and merge them into a long time series of daily profit numbers, and then perform analysis on them (charts, etc).

I then need to make it easy for the user to insert the data for xmay19.xlsx, etc and so on (from sheet "profit" in xmay19.xlsx, starting in B10).

What is the easiest way to do this?  I've just researched creating Excel connections from `Data > Connections` in "master.xlsx" and passing in tables in "master.xlsx", but this means I have a new sheet in "master.xlsx" for each month and then update the cells manually in the "profitovertime" sheet in "master.xlsx".

Is there a more seamless way to do this that offers more automation?

I imagine doing something like passing in a string giving the absolute file path of each month in a column of cells in some sheet in "master.xlsx", and then everything automatically updates in the master.xlsx's "profitovertime" sheet after only inputting the path to this new file.

Comment: If you are using excel 2013+ then use PowerQuery. If you want more specific help, then edit your question and post some screenshots of your data or a sample of the structure

Comment: Thanks! I had never heard of PowerQuery until you mentioned it.  Looks like that tool is just what I needed.

Comment: Great! Come back and post some data if you need any help